# java web application classpath

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am writing web app using spring. Which is created using standard web application.
I need `ApplicationContext` to be initialized using `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` so i placed context.xml file in WEB-INF folder and created `ApplicationContext`using following code.

`ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");`
But I get FileNotFoundException saying  context.xml is not found.
When i tried to initilize application using `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` it works.

But i want `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`
what can i do so that context.xml is located in classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place your context.xml inside classes folder or you can use

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:context.xml")
```

Read the below definition 
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext will read files from your classpath. They must be in classes folder of your web application or in a jar in your libfolder.
FileSystemXmlApplicationContext can access all your file system, for example c:/config/applicationContext.xml.
XmlWebApplicationContext certainly can access to files contained in your web application.